# SELECT query getting rows of table as columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have a MySQL database with two tables for questions and answers. Each question has a correct answer and three incorrect answers. There are always four answers for every question and only one is correct.

The tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE `question` (
  `id_question` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `text` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_question`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `answer` (
  `id_answer` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `id_question` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `is_correct` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(45) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_answer`,`id_question`),
  KEY `fk_id_question_idx` (`id_question`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I need help with a select query. I would like to get a table with questions in the rows and the four answers as columns (first the correct one and then the other three). So far I was able to get an output like this:

```
Question | Answer | Is_Correct
-------------------------------
Question 1   Answer 1-1   1
Question 1   Answer 1-2   0
Question 1   Answer 1-3   0
Question 1   Answer 1-4   0
Question 2   Answer 2-1   1
Question 2   Answer 2-2   0
Question 2   Answer 2-3   0
Question 2   Answer 2-4   0
...
```

How I can get the following result?

```
Question | Correct_Answer | Incorrect_answer1 | Incorrect_answer2 | Incorrect_answer3
--------------------------------------------------------------
Question 1    Answer 1-1    Answer 1-2    Answer 1-3    Answer 1-4
Question 2    Answer 2-1    Answer 2-2    Answer 2-3    Answer 2-4
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with pivot queries in MySQL, but that's a good place to start googling :).  Wish I could help more... I'm sure someone will post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *pivot* the data by using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression. You can use user-defined variables to implement a row number on each row by question. Your code will be similar to this:

```
select q.text Question,
  max(case when a.is_correct = 1 then a.text end) Correct_answer,
  max(case when a.is_correct = 0 and rn=1 then a.text end) Incorrect_Answer1,
  max(case when a.is_correct = 0 and rn=2 then a.text end) Incorrect_Answer2,
  max(case when a.is_correct = 0 and rn=3 then a.text end) Incorrect_Answer3
from question q
inner join
(
  select a.id_question,
    a.text,
    a.is_correct,
    a.id_answer,
    @row:=case 
            when @prevQ=id_question
              and is_correct = 0
            then @row +1 
            else 0 end  rn,
    @prevA:=id_answer,
    @prevQ:=id_question
  from answer a
  cross join (select @row:=0, @prevA:=0, @prevQ:=0)r
  order by a.id_question, a.id_answer
) a
  on q.id_question = a.id_question
group by q.text
order by a.id_question, a.id_answer
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7138/10). This gives the result in separate columns:

```
|   QUESTION | CORRECT_ANSWER | INCORRECT_ANSWER1 | INCORRECT_ANSWER2 | INCORRECT_ANSWER3 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Question 1 |     Answer 1-1 |        Answer 1-2 |        Answer 1-3 |        Answer 1-4 |
| Question 2 |     Answer 2-1 |        Answer 2-2 |        Answer 2-3 |        Answer 2-4 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructing a dynamic pivot query for this is a lot of work.  Instead, what I would probably do is use MySQL's [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function to create a comma-separated list of the `Incorrect_answer` fields, while separating out the `Correct_Answer` as its own column:

```
SELECT
  question.`text`,
  /* Separate the one where Is_Correct = 1 and discard the others with a MAX() aggregate */
  MAX(CASE WHEN Is_Correct = 1 THEN answer.`text` ELSE NULL END) AS Correct_Answer,
  /* Group the rows where Is_Correct = 0 into a comma-separated list */
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN Is_Correct = 0 THEN answer.`text` ELSE NULL END) AS Incorrect_answers
FROM
  question
  JOIN answer ON question.id_question = answer.id_question
GROUP BY Question.`text`
```

The result this produces as received by your application code looks like:

```
Question     Correct_Answer Incorrect_answers
--------------------------------------------------------------
Question 1    Answer 1-1    Answer 1-2,Answer 1-3,Answer 1-4
Question 2    Answer 2-1    Answer 2-2,Answer 2-3,Answer 2-4
```

It then becomes trivial in your application code to split the `Incorrect_answers` column on the `,` since it is a comma-separated list.

In PHP for example, something like :

```
$incorrect = explode(',', $row['Incorrect_answers']);
```

Or in Ruby or Python:

```
incorrect = incorrect_answers.split(',')
```